# Previewing images in a listBox using pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I am using Winforms to create a 2D Map Editor.

I want to be able to preview an image of my assets that are stored in listBox using a pictureBox.

My current code for doing so is thus.

```
    private void listBox_Assets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)listBox_Assets.SelectedItem).FullName);
    }
```

But when I select an asset I get this error.

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IO.FileInfo'.

I have searched high and low for a solution but can't find an answer to this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your code adding items to your `ListBox`.

Comment: This went wrong in your code that filled the ListBox.  You called its Items.Add() by passing a string, not a FileInfo object.  Which is okayish, just cast to string instead of FileInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the file name from the listbox like this, and protect the code with a check for the file.

```
private void listBox_Assets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = IO.Path.Combine("the directory", listBox_Assets.SelectedItem);
    if (IO.File.Exists(file)) 
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
}
```

Comment: No need to call `ToString` though

Comment: How do I do this without calling ToString? Or do I need to add something between the parentheses?

Comment: DonA, This got rid of my Casting error, but now it says the file can not be found, how can I direct it to the right place?

Comment: I can't see the file name you store in the listbox. Use the directory and add the file name to it.